# where does $tag parameter come from in wordpress actions and filters

Tags: wordpress, plugins, hook

we all know action in the wordpress work with this function

```
add_action( string $tag, callable $function_to_add, int $priority = 10, int $accepted_args = 1 )
```

all I want to know is that where does $tag parameter came from and actions and filter detect it and know where is the function that is related to this tag
and run the tag function we intend to run?

Comment: I am sure that if you provide some links of the articles and file addresses of what you are talking about you would get more attention and thus your question gets an answer easier.

Comment: Link of what article or address?

Comment: Anything about add_action and $tag parameter. Including these things might encourage someone outside wordpress community to read and help you out.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'widget_tag_cloud_args', 'twentysixteen_widget_tag_cloud_args' );

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'wpb_load_widget_top_10_main_page_blogs' );

function wpb_load_widget_top_10_main_page_blogs() {

    register_widget( 'wpb_widget_top_10_main_page_blogs' );
}
```

http://stackwordpress.com/search-filter-using-meta-query-with-wp-query/